# Syntax error, unexpected ' '. Please, (and no more)

Tags: php, rest, restful-authentication, controllers, laravel-3

Again, with some of modification "user.php" controller, mysterious error appear:

```
Unhandled Exception
Message:

syntax error, unexpected ''

Please,
```

... yes, that's all. I only modify user.php; here be gist: https://gist.github.com/pmache/17a8d037b89f275235ef

What I tried accomplish, is to register user with user, password, email and additionally - first name and last name. Then, (if proccess go ok) send mail with confirmation link to given adress, so user got validated.

Comment: Please, take a closer at the error and check your code, this is a total unnecessary question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the concatenation operator (`.`) at the end of [this line](https://gist.github.com/pmache/17a8d037b89f275235ef#file-gistfile1-txt-L84). It should be:

```
'<p>You need to confirm, that you want to join community</p>' .
'<p>Please, <a href="doNotClick"'.$user->id.'/'.htmlentities($user->validation_code).
```

Comment: Ok, simple fault of my brain. But, could you guide me what's wrong wth my code? When I try to register new user, and I'm putting correct values, errors come up with "Last name may cointains only letters" and "password confirmation do not match"

Comment: @user3235936 I'm not familiar with Laravel 3; you might be better off comparing your code with the Laravel 3 documentation perhaps.

Comment: Did it on my hand right before i had answer by you. Thank you sir.